# You tube video api, stop a video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

How to make this work for more than one video , I got it to work only one video

1. Include:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
   ```
2. Add your youtube iframe:

   ```
   <iframe id="player" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YOURID?rel=0&wmode=Opaque&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
   ```
3. Magic time:

   ```
   <script>
       var player;
       function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
           player = new YT.Player('player');
       }
       // so on jquery event or whatever call the play or stop on the video.
       // to play player.playVideo();
       // to stop player.stopVideo();
   </script>
   ```

Comment: I'm not quite clear on your question - would you be having a lot of iframes on your page?

Comment: yes different modal windows with iframes on them